# Transistor driven g6k/ud2 relay not work

Tags: transistors, relay

This is my part of schematic. The mcu controler is ESP8266 (io high = 3.3v proximity, P_GPIO4). I programmed and tested it to be works fine. But the relay never close/open and I can hear really faint current noise. The total power consumption approximate to 0.7~1.3W which seems to be abnormal.

3.3v and 5v power supply have been tested ok.

[image: the relay]
The PCB has been made and soldering by hand. It would be really nice if you can point out only component replacement needed.

Sorry, I fix the schematic. The R1 and R5 (gray) is not solder or can only be solder one of them.

Comment: Thanks everyone helps me there, and I also need some better (reliable, high efficiency) small-relay driver circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your relay contacts.

When K1 is energised the contacts will pull towards the relay coil. 6 connects to 5 and 3 connects to 4. Because R1 and R5 are 0 Ω, both of these contacts will short circuit the 5 V supply to GND, switch off the relay, open the contacts and the process will repeat quickly enough that it behaves like a buzzer.

Remove R1 or R5 and test again.

Comment: Thanks, I forget comments R1 R5 are not solder and they are using for power supply switching.